# Unable to Show image in HTML Container

Tags: html, css, image

I have just start the HTML from different tutorials. 
currently i want to show the **"Image"** in container. but image does not show the Container,image icon shown as : please see the below image : 
[image]

My HTML Code is  : 
[image]

How i solve this issue ?

Comment: Hi @Mudi Please make sure that the url of the image is correct.

Comment: Try to click on the link of your image in console, if you don't see the image .. your path is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks guys for you prompt replies!

Comment: @DHN3 Yes! I cannot see the image in console. it mean my path is incorrect. let me check that

Comment: When i go to console, the message is showing there is  :
"The warning message is "The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your path in your file system and then put the right link on your html.

So for example if your project are in :

```
D:\Desktop Folder\index.html
```

An image under the **same path** should be :

```
<img src="Ayan.jpg" />
```

If your image is under a folder called '*images*' it will be :

```
<img src="images/Ayan.jpg" />
```